# Platzhalter vs. Stellvertreter

Tags: grammar, difference, pronoun, expletiva

I see some sentences in German, where some say that *es* is a *Platzhalter*, while some say it is a *Stellvertreter*. Now I wonder, are these words interchangeable?

For example, in the following sentence is *es* a Platzhalter or Stellvertreter?

> Mir wird geholfen → es wird mir geholfen.

Comment: Welcome to German SE. Please elaborate by showing us the sentence you are talking about.

Comment: Additionally, feel free to take the [tour] and consult the [help] for questions about the site. And please observe spelling rules such as spaces after full stops and commas and capitalised *I*.

Comment: Oh ***that*** is what you mean!

Comment: Someone (with more experience than me) should also edit the tags of this question

Comment: @WalterTross Done.

Answer (score 3):

This confusion of yours is maybe why people should stick to Latin names for grammatical phaenomena.

In your example sentence

> Es wird mir geholfen.

*es* has no function other than filling the *Vorfeld,* the area before the verb. Therefore, it is an expletive; there only for syntactic reasons. The correct German name for this is *Expletiv.* If you really wanted to translate it into German, I would use *Platzhalter,* because it occupies the space that would otherwise be unfilled without carrying a meaning.

However, there are other sentences where *es* functions as a pronoun.

> Es ist ein hübsches Bild.

*Es,* here, is referring to certain picture known somehow by context or by direct reference. The correct name would be pronoun or *Pronomen* but if one really wanted to use a German word, I would recommend *Stellvertreter,* because it *substitutes* the other word which was considered too long by the writer/speaker.

Comment: _Vorfeld_  is Latin now? 

Comment: @Crissov Nah, I just never knew a Latinoid/English name for that. That is, I probably read one once but forgot. ;)

Comment: what about "Stellvertretend" in my example for "mir"?
sie hilft mir ==> mir wird von ihr geholfen.

Comment: @user1474062 No. That is just a reordered way of saying the same thing. *Es* is not required grammatically, it is only there if the *Vorfeld* would otherwise be empty, hence expletive.