# Parsing "es schien ihr die Lust zur Musik schon vergangen zu sein"

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure, pronoun, expletiva

The question is on the *es schien* clause as highlighted in these excerpts from Kafka's *Der Verschollene*.

> »Was Sie für eilige Geschäfte haben«, sagte Klara und ordnete zerstreut die Falten ihres losen Nachtkleides. Ihr Gesicht glühte und immerfort lächelte sie. **Karl glaubte zu erkennen, daß keine Gefahr bestand, mit Klara wieder in Streit zu geraten.** »Könnten Sie nicht doch noch ein wenig Klavier spielen, wie es mir gestern Papa und heute Sie selbst versprochen haben?«
>        »Ist es nicht aber schon zu spät?« fragte Karl. Er hätte ihr gern gefällig sein wollen, denn sie war ganz anders als vorher, so als wäre sie irgendwie aufgestiegen in die Kreise Pollunders und weiterhin Macks.
>        »Ja, spät ist es schon«, sagte sie, und **es schien ihr die Lust zur Musik schon vergangen zu sein.** »Dann widerhallt hier auch jeder Ton im ganzen Hause, ich bin überzeugt, wenn Sie spielen, wacht noch oben in der Dachkammer die Dienerschaft auf.«

Which of the following is the right way to read it?

**Reading 1**

- *es* is a cataphoric (kataphorisch, vorausweisend) reference to *die Lust zur Musik*.
- The clause is a stylistic variation of:  *die Lust zur Musik schien ihr schon vergangen zu sein.*
- The clause can be assimilated to things like:  *It seems to work, what you did.*
- *scheinen* takes two arguments:  scheinen(thing, attribute), where the attribute could be in the form of adjective instead of infinitive.

I realize each of these things may be different so that someone can accept one but not another.

**Reading 2**

- *scheinen* is an impersonal verb.
- *es scheinen* takes one argument:  es-scheinen(a state of affairs), where the state of affairs could have been a *dass* clause instead of infinitive.

On this reading, by which *die Lust* is subject for *sein* and has only a distant relationship to *es schien*, I wonder what would be its grammatical case.  The accusative?

(I guess if we had *den Wunsch* in place of *die Lust*, I would not have posted this question.  If we had *der Wunsch*, I would still have wondered whether *zu sein* took a subject in the nominative.)

**Karl glaubte**

You don't need to read what follows to answer the question.

It seems on reading 2 the *es schien* clause can be assimilated to the *Karl glaubte*.  *Karl glaubte* also introduces a state of affairs, namely that Karl recognized something.  (Of course *Karl* as "subject" of *erkennen* is supressed.)

On reading 1, *es schien* cannot be assimilated to *Karl glaubte* because *glaubte* already has its own subject.  That its subject and the (suppressed) subject of *erkennen* happen to be the same person is just an accident.

Comment: I don't know if it helps you, but you could also say: "es schien, dass ihr die Lust zur Musik schon vergangen war."

Comment: Reading 1 is essentially right, but _es_ is a placeholder to fill the position in front of the verb (which needs to be in second position).

Comment: See also http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/platzhalter-vs-stellvertreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Observation 1:**
*Es* cannot be cataphoric because in that case *die Lust zur Musik* would require a cataphoric *sie:*

> Sie schien ihr vergangen, die Lust zur Musik.

**Observation 2:**
The clause is indeed a variant of:

> Die Lust zur Musik schien ihr schon vergangen zu sein.

**Observation 3:**
The clause can be assimilated to:

> Es scheint zu funktionieren.

**Observation 4:**
*Scheinen* needs two arguments:

> <strike>Es scheint die Lust zur Musik vergangen</strike> is missing something.

The *es* at the beginning of the sentence is not in any way a reference to what is coming. It is merely a *syntactic expletive* because Kafka wanted to put the two arguments of *scheinen* behind the verb. Note that this is not possible with every verb in every situation <strike>‘Es gehe ich nach Hause’</strike> but sometimes works for verbs that have a rather impersonal picture to them.

Both clauses have a subject. For *Karl glaubte* it is, of course, *Karl.* For *es schein …* it is *die Lust zur Musik,* which, as Carsten correctly pointed out, must be nominative case (can be replaced by *der Spaß an der Musik*).

Comment: Thanks! Is *expletiv* not a German noun? A quick Web search seems to turn up only adjectival uses, e.g. *das expletive es*, *mit expletivem Subjekt*. A dictionary gives *Füllwort*.  Anyway, something unfortunate happened to the word in English. http://theweek.com/articles/443704/how-did-expletive-explicit-exploit-become-such-sleazy-words

Comment: @Catomic The noun exists, however also does the more Latin variant *Expletivum.* See [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since I am not well-versed in grammar, I do not understand all parts of your question. I do however think that your reading 1 is more accurate. What I can tell you with certainty is that *die Lust* is in the nominative case. As a native speaker I only have to replace *Lust* by a maculine word like *Spaß* to see that.

> Es schien ihr der Spaß an der Musik schon vergangen zu sein.

(*Not* the exact same meaning.)

The construction seems to me to be the same as in the simpler sentence

> Es steht ein Mann vor dem Haus.

A construction that would maybe tend towards your second reading would require (almost, compare [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18088/wortstellung-mit-glauben/18110?s=2|0.0848#18110)) a relative clause:

> Es schien, dass ihr die Lust zur Musik schon vergangen war.