# verb conjugation; es sind - when can one use this?

Tags: conjugation

When can one use the construction 'es sind'? 'Es' is third person singular and 'sind' is a plural verb conjugation so they look odd together.

Comment: You want to look up *Es* in the dictionary - It's one of the few words in German that look the same in both singular and plural and in all cases. So your claim "it's singular" is wrong.

Comment: Actually, when used as a pronoun, there is a plural: "sie". *Wo ist das Kind? Es ist in der Schule.* / *Wo sind die Kinder? Sie sind in der Schule.* However, *es* is often not a pronoun but a mere placeholder, and in this case there is no distinct plural.

Comment: "Es ist" and "Es sind" in this context are respectively equivalent to English "There is" and "There are" .

Comment: @NetwOrchestration: Also, notice the usage "Es sind 25 Grad", which translates into "It's 25 degrees centigrade".

Answer (score 9):

The pronoun "es" is not only used as a personal pronoun (like er, sie, es, …). It has several more functions in German. In these functions "es" is sometimes called a placeholder, or impersonal "es" or empty "es" (unpersönliches "es", leeres "es"), or a "dummy pronoun". A linguistic term is »expletives "es"« / English: syntactic expletive. What it means is that it fills an otherwise empty spot of a subject or object in a sentence construction. It is in this function that "es" stands independent of gender and number.

Typical example of "es" filling the place of a subject:

> Es sind sechs Eier in der Packung. / Sechs Eier sind in der Packung.
>   
>  Es ist ein Ei in der Packung. / Ein Ei ist in der Packung.

The question is now, why would anyone use such a sentence construction in the first place?

To an English speaker the difference should become clear in the translation:

> There are six eggs in the package. / Six eggs are in the package.
>   There is one egg in the package. / One egg is in the package.

More thorough info can be found here:  [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-es.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, [*es* looks like a subject but is not](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37476/sentence-with-two-subjects/). For example in

> Es sind zwei Rosen entsprungen.

the subject is *zwei Rosen*, and *es* only fills the first position so that the verb is in second position. This can be reordered to

> Zwei Rosen sind entsprungen.

Here, the *es* is not needed any more.

Comment: My example is a stupid joke, btw, usually roses do not jump.

Answer (score 0):

Es sind (!) hier unten einige Beispiele typischer Verwendung aufgeführt:

> Es sind noch viele Packungen Bohnen im Tiefkühlschrank.
>
> Es sind mir zu viele Scharlatane im gegenwärtigen US-amerikanischen Kabinett.
>
> Es sind doch keine Kleinigkeiten, die Sie da falsch gemacht haben!
>
> Es sind 40 Liter Regen pro Quadratmeter gefallen.
>
> Es sind die kleinen Gesten, die die Freundschaft erhalten.
>
> Es sind noch Nudeln da!