# Confusing Konjunktiv I conjugation

Tags: subjunctive, conjugation

Consider the following aphorism by Nietzsche:

> Ich liebe Die, welche nicht zu leben wissen, es sei denn als Untergehende, denn es sind die Hinübergehenden.

I unterstand that the cluster *es sei denn* means *unless*, however, in the last sub-sentence, why is *sind* used if, apparently, the subject is *es*? Should one not use *sei* instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [verb conjugation; es sind - when can one use this?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38085/verb-conjugation-es-sind-when-can-one-use-this)

Answer (score 3):

*Es sei denn* is a fixed phrase that does not influence what follows; especially, there is no need for it to be followed by the present subjunctive. Note that *sind* isn't present subjunctive, but indicative; the former would be *seien*.

The question remains why singular *es* is followed by plural *sind*. This happens when *es* is the subject and a plural noun phrase is the subject complement.

> Schau dir mal die Fotos an. Es *(subject)* sind einige meiner besten Aufnahmen *(subject complement)*.

Note that the grammatical structure changes completely in cases such as the following.

> Schau dir mal die Fotos an. Es *(expletive)* sind einige meiner besten Aufnahmen *(subject)* **darunter** *(subject complement)*.

The expletive *es* has no grammatical function and disappears when the sentence is rearranged.

> Schau dir mal die Fotos an. Einige meiner besten Aufnahmen sind darunter.

Answer (score 3):

That *es* is the same kind of *it* as in the English phrase *It rains.*

You need it for grammar reasons but it's not the subject of that clause. The real subject is *die Hinübergehenden*, which is plural. Hence *es sind*, not *es ist*.

Now you can ask why it's not *es seien*. This is because that part of the sentence is neither stated as hearsay nor as an assignment. But as a fact.

That *es sei denn* in the previous clause isn't an assignment either. It's a pre-packaged phrase meaning *unless*.