# Why is the following example in the nominative instead of accusative?

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun, accusative, nominative

> Ich möchte noch Wein. Haben wir noch welchen?
>
> Nein, es ist keiner mehr da.

I understand why the first part has "welchen" in the accusative, but unsure of the reasoning behind "keiner" being the nominative. How is "keiner" the subject of the sentence here?

Comment: Look at the verb.

Comment: Does nominative always come after "sein"?

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting grammatical question because the semantic subject ("Wein") and the semantic predicate of the sentence "nicht mehr da" do not correspond to their grammatical entities. It would be a pity if the question should be closed. In particular, I cannot figure out why this grammatical question should be off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

**Sein** is the *copula*, it takes a nominative "object". It's the same in English but you usually can't see the difference there.

> Wer ist **sie**? — Sie ist die Königin von England, du Doofie!
>
> Who is **she**? — She's the Queen of England, dummy!

If that was accusative, it has to be *her* in English. And in the above special case, it's English which uncovers the nominative, while in German, nominative and accusative of *sie* are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common sentence with a very weird grammatical structure.

I think the most simple way to understand this structure is by assuming the following idiomatic predicate expression with the meaning *"to be available in the specified quantity"*:

> Es ist/sind **[quantifier]** **[nominative part]** da.

Examples:

> Es ist ein Buch da.
>   Es sind zwei Bücher da.
>   Es sind genug Bücher da.
>   Es sind viele Bücher da.
>   Es sind wenige Bücher da.
>   Es sind keine Bücher da.
>
> ---
>
> Es ist ein Liter Wein da.
>   Es sind zwei Liter Wein da.
>   Es sind viele Liter Wein da.
>   Es sind wenige Liter Wein da.
>   Es ist kein Liter Wein da.
>
> ---
>
> Es ist Wein da.
>   Es ist genug Wein da.
>   Es ist viel Wein da.
>   Es ist wenig Wein da.
>   Es ist kein Wein da.

As can be seen in the examples, the verb is congruent ("ist/sind") to the nominative part before *da*. Hence this nominative part is **indeed the subject** and not a nominative object.

In German, an expression of form *"kein Wein"* can be substituted for the negative pronoun *"keiner"*. So, the last example sentence turns into:

> Es ist keiner da.

The adverbial attribute *"mehr"* added, you get:

> Es ist keiner mehr da.

I have to admit that from a grammatical point of view this sentence structure is an exceptional one despite of being in heavy use.

Comment: Well explained, apart from explaining why this should be a "very weird grammatical" construction. What do you consider weird?

Comment: @Beta A **not** weird grammatical sentence construction consists of a subject and a predicate where subject can always take the **first** place in a sentence. That's not the case here. A not weird sentence can be turned into a question just by moving the subject behind the verb of the predicate without any other changes on the sentence. That's not the case here either. And some further oddities.

Comment: What we have here is that the subject moved away from the first position and a *Platzhalter-es* takes this position. This has already been discussed, e.g. in https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37476/sentence-with-two-subjects/37482

Comment: @RHa That's right. But in this case it's more than that.