# Which is correct, es sind zwei Eier übrig or es ist zwei Eier übrig? And why?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which is correct:

Es sind zwei Eier übrig geblieben.

Es ist zwei Eier übrig geblieben.

As a native speaker, I would go with Es ist ein Ei übrig geblieben but also Es sind zwei Eier übrig geblieben.

Am I correct?

Comment: Also see https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37476/sentence-with-two-subjects

Comment: You don't know this as a native speaker?!

Comment: @infinitezero I do, as I was correct, I asked this question to settle an argument with a non-native speaker who thought otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. It is indeed *Es sind zwei Eier übrig (geblieben)*.

The verb *(übrig) sein* - to be (left over) - in this case must agree with the noun number of the sentence's subject *Eier*; thus *ist* in the case of one egg only (singular), and *sind* in all other instances (plural).

The confusion even to a native speaker may stem from the unchangeable pronoun *es*, which is an idiomatically split particle of the sentence's subject. You can paraphrase your sentence by omitting *es*, to *ein Ei ist übrig* or *zwei Eier sind übrig* and still render the exact same meaning but with slightly lower emphasis.