# Understanding the subject of sentence

Tags: adverb, grammar-identification, subordinate-clause, personal-pronoun

> Ich erwähne dieses Beispiel, **weil gerade in ihm zum Ausdruck kommt,** dass
>   ...

Above sentence is from Canoo.net [*Pronominal adverbs refer to "non-persons"*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Pronomen/PronAdv/Funktion.html?lang=en)

My question is about not understanding the subject of the above bolded sentence, though I have written my assumption below.

Is the subject **es** ignored in the above bolded sentence?
Like if I write the sentence with *es* as below, would it have the same meaning as the sentence above:

> weil es gerade in ihm zum Ausdruck kommt, dass...

Answer (score 4):

The subject is the clause starting with *dass*. In general, *es* can be used to indicate that a sentential subject or object follows. In German, this is known as *Korrelat* ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korrelat_(Grammatik))).

> **Dass du nicht kommen kannst**, ist so gesehen bedauerlich.
>   So gesehen ist **es** bedauerlich, **dass du nicht kommen kannst.** (Korrelat-es)

In the example you cited, however, *es* does sound quite bad. At first, I thought this was because *es* could be interpreted as referring back to *dieses Beispiel*:

> Ich erwähne **dieses Beispiel**, weil **es** schwierig ist. (anaphorisches Personalpronomen)

I then tried to show that *Korrelat-es* could be used with *zum Ausdruck kommen*:

> Es kommt zum Ausdruck, was das eigentliche Problem ist. (Platzhalter-es)

However, this is nonsense! The word *es* in the above example is limited to position 1 and cannot occur after the verb (the asterisk in the following example indicates ungrammaticality):

> *Dort kommt es zum Ausdruck, was das eigentliche Problem ist.

This type of *es* is known as *Platzhalter* (see [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/platzhalter-vs-stellvertreter)).

The question that remains is: Why is there no *Korrelat* allowed in the last example? I now think this may be related to the following fixed expression:

> Es kommt zu X. – *There is X; X happens, comes to pass.* (unpersönliches Es)
>
> Es kam zu Tumulten. – *There were riots.*
>   Wie kam es denn dazu? – *How did that happen?*
>   Und so kam es, dass wir uns verliebten. – *And so it came about we fell in love.*

Hypothesis: Because there is a fixed expression involving *unpersönliches Es*, *kommen zu* does not allow *Korrelat-es*.

Comment: Zur neuen Rechtschreibung genötigt!

Comment: So haben wir beschlossen: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/831/when-editing-a-post-may-or-even-should-we-change-pre-reform-spelling-to-post-re

Comment: Tyrannei der Mehrheit...

Comment: How "weil" would be understood in the sentence because I have not encountered with sentence whose main clause start with conjunction (weil)  when subordinated clause is a subject of the sentence?